# How Tomcat Notify about When New Jsp being uploaded

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, java-web-start

when we directly upload JSP page into tomcat where application deployed directory then why we don't need to restart Tomcat? how tomcat know that it has new JSP page?

when user hit the url /myapp/mynewjsp.jsp  He/She always get new jsp deployed page.

Comment: Take a look inside the Tomcat source code and the JSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat has an auto deploy feature. When you update JSP files it detects you have done so, compiles it, and replaces the old compiled JSP page with the new one that it compiles into a java class.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

If you don't want that to happen, you can turn off the auto deploy feature for your web application. It is described in the link how you do that.

Comment: i just want to clear the concept.if we deploy .class file directly then a restart is must. but if we replace jsp,then restart is not required.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, it's because JSP files (or their compiled .class equivalents) does not hold state, but your other classes do since they have fields.

Autoloading classes holding state is very risky, for that reason, when the code is in production.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it helped you, so people can see this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can  use jetty plugin for auto deploying tomcat folder . You don't need to paste your file on webapps folder. If you using maven project structure then add jetty plugin on pom.xml file . There is some command to run  like mvn jetty:run etc... May these solution get you out from these problem

Comment: sorry,Darshan i am not asking about deployment.I just want to know, about the Tomcat intelligence about deployment.